# How to change DataGrid Row color on Checkbox clicked?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I've spend a lot of time trying to change row text color on CheckBox click event.

So we need set color to gray if checkbox is checked and return it to normal color if checkbox is not checked.

Please help to get this result (DataGrid bound to xml file).

Upd. Some code:

XAML for row color changing based on column Checked (Checkbox):

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding Checked, Converter={x:Static local:MainWindow.rowCheckedConverter}}" />
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

...
<Grid.DataContext>
   <XmlDataProvider x:Name="userTasksProvider" XPath="UserTasks" />
</Grid.DataContext>
...

<DataGrid Name="dgUserTasks" Grid.Column="1" Margin="1,0,0,0"
   AutoGenerateColumns="False" HeadersVisibility="None"
   ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=Task}">

   <DataGrid.Columns>
   <DataGridCheckBoxColumn x:Name="cbUserTasksColumn" Width="20"
      Binding="{Binding Checked,
      Mode=TwoWay}" Header="">
   </DataGridCheckBoxColumn>

   <DataGridTextColumn 
      x:Name="Info" Width="*"
      Binding="{Binding Info,
      Mode=TwoWay}"
      Header="" >
   </DataGridTextColumn>
...
```

C# WPF:

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public static RowCheckedConverter rowCheckedConverter = new RowCheckedConverter();
        ...
    }

    ...

    public class RowCheckedConverter : IValueConverter {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) {

            if ((bool)value) {
                return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Gray);
            }
            else {
                return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
            }

        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) {
            throw new Exception("The method or operation is not implemented.");
        }
    }
```

Comment: -1 because it is not stated if the checkbox bool value is part of the itemssource collection or not. and this is essential for the answer. provide some code and i will remove the downvote and you will get some better help also ;)

Comment: Thanks, source code provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is quite vague but I'll try to help.

Consider this example:

```
 <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding DataSet}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.RowStyle>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsActive}" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Gray"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.RowStyle>
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}">
            </DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{Binding IsActive, Mode=TwoWay}">

            </DataGridCheckBoxColumn>

        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

and code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection<Data> DataSet { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        DataSet = new ObservableCollection<Data>();
        DataSet.Add(new Data { Name = "First" });
        DataSet.Add(new Data { Name = "Second" });
        DataSet.Add(new Data { Name = "Third" });
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
    }

}

public class Data
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
}
```

In this snippet I bound checkbox column to property in Data instance and added style trigger when this property is false. Is this what you where looking for?

**Edit after question update**

I cannot see in code that your provided where your style is assigned to DataGrid:

```
<DataGrid  RowStyle="{StaticResource myStyle}" ...>
```

and your style does not declare x:Key property.

If you add this it will work but the static fied/property just smells bad. Consider changing to:

```
<Style TargetType="DataGridRow" x:Key="myStyle">
    <Style.Triggers>
          <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Checked}" Value="False">
               <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Gray"/>
          </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

If you are determined to use converter consider changning to:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}" x:Key="myStyle">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" >
        <Setter.Value>
            <Binding Path="Checked">
                <Binding.Converter>
                    <local:RowCheckedConverter />
                </Binding.Converter>
            </Binding>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

This will also eliminate this field.

Comment: Rafal, thank you very much for the quick answer. You code seems to work. But i can't make it work with XmlDataProvider (bound to xml file)...

Comment: If you say the answer is correct/helpful then why wont you accept it?

Comment: Rafael, this is my first question on StackOverflow, and i can't see any buttons to "accept it"..

Answer (score 0):

Use a converter like shown here: http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2008/07/30/format-data-in-silverlight-databinding-valueconverter.aspx